# Access to the Application Options from the File drop down

Tags: revit-api

I would like to access and record user's Options settings to a remote database.

We often have users tweaking local settings; hardware acceleration, worksharing refresh rates, file template locations, etc...

I'd like to record these and compare them againts a "master list" to assist in trouble shooting issues when they arise, or proactively address them.

Looking through the Application name space, i don't see anything besides 'LibrarPaths', 'defaultProjectemplate' and FamilyTemplatePath'.

Does anyone know if i can get access to this information from with in revit, or if it is stored in a file somewhere or the registry?

Answer (score 2):

The Revit API can only be used from within a valid Revit API context. Therefore, reading data from the Revit API `Application` object is only possible from within such a context. You can obtain a valid API context by implementing an external command. In that case, the end user will have to click a button in the UI to launch the command. Please read the [Revit API getting started material](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/about-the-author.html#2) for a detailed explanation.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy.  I think I was unclear in my question.  I meant THROUGH the API.  It's been weeks since I was working on this one, but I couldn't seem to find access to "options" in the ApplicationServices namespace.

Comment: Such application wide setting would not be store in the Revit database, since such data is project specific. So, it must be somewhere else. The only place that comes to mind is the registry and the ini file. You can try to twiddle the setting and research where the modifications are stored. I am not aware of any official API access to the settings you mention.